# Kafka: What is Current Offset or Record Count of Topic?

Tags: apache-kafka

How do I get the current offset, or offset by partition, or record count for a given topic? It doesn't need to be perfect, but I want a ballpark idea of how much data is in a Kafka topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the offset for the partitions of a topic you can use  [kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/System+Tools)

```
./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic your_topic_name --time -1
```

If you want to get the latest offset for a particular group, you can also use:

```
./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker  --topic your_topic_name--zookeeper localhost:2181 --group your_group_id
```

In order to count the entries within a topic, you can either consume the whole topic (when you stop the consumer the total number of consumed messages will be reported). Alternatively, you can use

```
./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell  --broker-list <broker>:  <port> --topic <topic-name> --time -1 --offsets 1 | awk -F  ":" '{sum += $3} END {print sum}'
```